# Find joint distribution function in region

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I can't for the life of me figure this one out, I am stuck on part (c) ...

[image: question 2 c]

I have this as my starting point ?

$$
\frac{45}{304}\int_0^x\int_{2-x}^2 u^2v^2\,\mathrm{du} \mathrm{dv}
$$

Here is my sketch for part a:
[image: sketch for part a]

The problem I am having is that when I try to calculate the entire CDF for all ranges it sums to more than 1 :( which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that you chose $c = \frac{45}{304}$ which seems arbitrary (or how did you get that exact value?). $c$ should be chosen so that the integral of $f$ is $1$.

Comment: @flawr This is how i found c? [Question 2B Answer](http://i.imgur.com/s9zYiPY.jpg)

Comment: You should compare your solution to the computer caluclated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[My CAS](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Climits_0%5Ex%20%5Cint%5Climits_%7B2-x%7D%5E2%20u%5E2%20v%5E2%20du%20dv%20for%20x%3D2) tells me

$$ \int\limits_0^x \int\limits_{2-x}^2 u^2 v^2 du dv = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{8}{3}- \frac{1}{3} (2-x)^3\right) x^3$$

This expressoin evaluated at $x=2$ is $\frac{64}{9}$ So $c$ should be chosen as $c=\frac{9}{64}$ and I think this is where the error was?